# Problem with appending falsey value into another list

Tags: python

Now I am working in a python exercise, which is return the middle values in a nested list and form a new nested lists:

```
peel_layer_off([
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
  ["i", "j", "k", "l"],
  ["m", "n", "o", "p"]
]) ➞ [
  ["f", "g"],
  ["j", "k"]
]

peel_layer_off([
  [True, False, True],
  [False, False, True],
  [True, True, True]
]) ➞ [[False]]
```

What I am trying to do is to form a nested loop, return a list with all the elements in the middle of the sublists and append to the main list:

```
def peel_layer_off(lst):
    returnlist = []
    for x in lst:
        z = [y for y in x if x.index(y) > 0 and x.index(y) < len(x) - 1]
        returnlist.append(z)

    return returnlist[1:len(returnlist) - 1]

print(peel_layer_off([
  [True, False, True],
  [False, False, True],
  [True, True, True]
])
)
```

For the first example, the test passed.
However, for the second example, what I got is  `[[]]` instead of `[[False]]`

Can I know why is that and if I really need to return all falsey value into the list, what can I do?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your problem is you are using `.index` here. Don't do that, first is *wrong* because it gives you the *first index of a given value in a list*,  and second, it is a very inefficient way to get an index in a loop. But you should just use slicing, like you already did, `[sub[1:-1] for sub in data[1:-1]]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the reply. But for the .index, you said that it gives you the first index of a given value in a list -- Since I am still new to Python, can you explain me more for that?

Comment: `[1,2,3,1].index(1)` will **always return 0**. but when you are iterating over the list and are at the last item, the last 1, you need it to return `3`, but it will always give you `0`

Answer (score 2):

Change `peel_layer_off` to the following:

```
def peel_layer_off(lst):
    returnlist = []
    for x in lst:
        z = x[1 : -1]
        returnlist.append(z)

    return returnlist[1 : -1]
```

1. Instead of `returnlist[1 : len(returnlist) - 1]` you can write `returnlist[1 : -1]`.
2. Your whole subsetting of `x` inside the `for` loop can be equivalently simplified.

Better yet, using list comprehension instead of a `for` loop:

```
def peel_layer_off(lst):
    ret = [x[1 : -1] for x in lst]
    return ret[1 : -1]
```

… this could also be written as a one-liner (without the temporary variable `ret`), but IMHO at the cost of readability.

Comment: Rodolph It works and thanks! But still wonder, why we can get the correct value with slicing method but wrong value with the original dump approach?

Comment: @PakHangLeung See Juan’s answer under your question.